# How would you rewrite a SASS extends

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass

How would you rewrite this SCSS code to make it pass the build

```
  .form-check-label input[type='checkbox']:focus + label::before {
    @extend .form-control:focus;
  }
```

When I ran my compile SASS it says to replace `@extend .form-control:focus;` with `@extend .form-control, :focus;` but it breaks my site.

Is there any way to rewrite the above SCSS?

Comment: can you provide a snippet ? try sassmeister.com

Comment: [compound selectors may no longer be extended](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/extend-compound), you could use a `mixin` instead.

Comment: Bootstrap 4 [Checkboxes and radios](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios) documentation guides us that `.form-check-label` is applied to `<label>` element and `.form-check-input` is applied to `<input>` element. Both these elements then grouped in `.form-check` div elem. Seems no usage for `.form-control` or `:focus` pseudo state here? Can you please provide some form checkbox html for what you are trying to target and focus?